# Why do Entity Framework Core migrations require .NET Core 2.x?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-5

In my .NET5.0 project the PostgreSQL Nuget package is installed (`Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgrSQL (5.0.2)`) and its dependency of EF Core (`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (5.0.2)`).

I'm trying to create a migration using this command:

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate
```

However, the migration fails because I'm requested to install .NET Core 2.0.0 - following the recommended download link I'm told that it's no longer available and that I would likely want to use 5.0. How the heck can I run the migration?

This is what the output looks:

```
Build started...
Build succeeded.
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '2.0.0' was not found.
  - The following frameworks were found:
      3.1.11 at [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
      3.1.12 at [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
      3.1.13 at [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
      5.0.3 at [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
      5.0.4 at [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.

The specified framework can be found at:
  - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=2.0.0&arch=x64&rid=osx.11.0-x64
```

Comment: What is the version of `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools`?

Comment: Entity Framework Core .NET Command-line Tools 5.0.4

Comment: post your app.csproj, you probably have any package which has dependency on core 2.x

Comment: Before using any of the EF tools, my project worked just fine and it's all .NET 5.0.

Comment: I have the same issue, did you manage to find a resolution @Krumelur?

Comment: Any answer for this?

Answer (score 8):

Make sure you have `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="5.0.5" />` in your csproj. Also try updating the dotnet-ef tool: `dotnet tool update --global dotnet-ef`.

I performed these actions and the issue went away.

Comment: Like a charm. You save my day.

Comment: Did not solve the problem for me ...

Answer (score 6):

This can occur if you run the command in a class library.
You can point to the `startup-project` when running the command:

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate --startup-project <PathToProject>
```

Comment: This is also the solution if you have split the projects based on different db providers to get migrations to work, you only need to add `--project <PathToPostgresDbProject>` to the solution above. And run the command once per provider.